# live video streaming from an android phone to vlc streaming server and finally to end clients eg. web browsers

Tags: android, iis, vlc, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I want to do a **live streaming from android phone**.
I created the mobile part and able to send video data in bytes format to server.

On server side I am able to read that, but want to broadcast it using vlc server to end client browsers.

I am able to configure **vlc streaming** for screen capturer and able to show in browsers using ogg/thoera format.

I m stuck in linking received byte as input stream to vlc.

I would appreciate if u can suggest other appropriate way to achieve the same.

How can I steam the same to IIS Live video smooth streaming **publish points**.

Thanx,
**Shivam**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this Android app
http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/